# SVG Select color map

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm working in a game in js. it's a war game.
if I hover on an country/select is gives an border and a color but I want, if I own the country it has his own color.
You can see it if you select a country and click on "selecteren" on the left. 
Select a country other than USA, brazil, russia, china, canada and india.
Then it had a green border but I want the country colered. http://w0w.eu

HTML code of a country:

```
<g data-name="indonesia">
<path id="kalimantan" d="M781.68,324.4l-2.31,8.68l-12.53,4.23l-3.75-4.4l-1.82,0.5l3.4,13.12l5.09,0.57l6.79,2.57v2.57l3.11-0.57l4.53-6.27v-5.13l2.55-5.13l2.83,0.57l-3.4-7.13l-0.52-4.59L781.68,324.4L781.68,324.4z"/>
<path id="sumatra" d="M722.48,317.57l-0.28,2.28l6.79,11.41h1.98l14.15,23.67l5.66,0.57l2.83-8.27l-4.53-2.85l-0.85-4.56L722.48,317.57L722.48,317.57z"/>
<path id="java" d="M753.17,358.32l-2.75,1.88l0.59,1.58l8.75,1.98l4.42,0.79l1.87,1.98l5.01,0.4l2.36,1.98l2.16-0.5l1.97-1.78l-3.64-1.68l-3.14-2.67l-8.16-1.98L753.17,358.32L753.17,358.32z"/>
<path id="bali" d="M781.77,366.93l-2.16,1.19l1.28,1.39l3.14-1.19L781.77,366.93L781.77,366.93z"/>
<path id="lombok" d="M785.5,366.04l0.39,1.88l2.26,0.59l0.88-1.09l-0.98-1.49L785.5,366.04L785.5,366.04z"/>
<path id="sumba" d="M790.91,370.99l-2.75,0.4l2.46,2.08h1.96L790.91,370.99L790.91,370.99z"/>
<path id="flores" d="M791.69,367.72l-0.59,1.19l4.42,0.69l3.44-1.98l-1.96-0.59l-3.14,0.89l-1.18-0.99L791.69,367.72L791.69,367.72z"/>
<path id="timor" d="M806.14,368.42l-5.11,4.26l0.49,1.09l2.16-0.4l2.55-2.38l5.01-0.69l-0.98-1.68L806.14,368.42L806.14,368.42z"/>
<path id="sulawesi" d="M789.53,349.11l2.26,2.77l-1.47,4.16v0.79h3.34l1.18-10.4l1.08,0.3l1.96,9.5l1.87,0.5l1.77-4.06l-1.77-6.14l-1.47-2.67l4.62-3.37l-1.08-1.49l-4.42,2.87h-1.18l-2.16-3.17l0.69-1.39l3.64-1.78l5.5,1.68l1.67-0.1l4.13-3.86l-1.67-1.68l-3.83,2.97h-2.46l-3.73-1.78l-2.65,0.1l-2.95,4.75l-1.87,8.22L789.53,349.11L789.53,349.11z"/>
<path id="maluku" d="M814.19,330.5l-1.87,4.55l2.95,3.86h0.98l1.28-2.57l0.69-0.89l-1.28-1.39l-1.87-0.69L814.19,330.5L814.19,330.5z"/>
<path id="seram" d="M819.99,345.45l-4.03,0.89l-1.18,1.29l0.98,1.68l2.65-0.99l1.67-0.99l2.46,1.98l1.08-0.89l-1.96-2.38L819.99,345.45L819.99,345.45z"/>
<path id="west papua" d="M831.93,339.34l-4.17,0.47l-2.68,1.96l1.11,2.24l4.54,0.84v0.84l-2.87,2.33l1.39,4.85l1.39,0.09l1.2-4.76h2.22l0.93,4.66l10.83,8.96l0.28,7l3.7,4.01l1.67-0.09l0.37-24.72l-6.29-4.38l-5.93,4.01l-2.13,1.31l-3.52-2.24l-0.09-7.09L831.93,339.34L831.93,339.34z"/>
```

CSS code:

```
path:hover{
fill: #E2E2E2!important;
stroke-width: 1px;
stroke: #2B2B2B;
}

g.selected{
stroke-width: 1px;
stroke: #2B2B2B;
fill: #D2D2D2!important;
}
path[data-owned=true]{
fill: #D2D2D2!important;
stroke-width: 1px;
stroke: #3FDA4E;

}
g[data-owned=true]{ 
fill: #D2D2D2!important;
stroke-width: 1px;
stroke: #3FDA4E;
```

}

```
this.addCountry     =   function(country){
    if(this.countries.indexOf(country) >= 0){
        alert("You already own this country");
        return false;
    }
    this.countries.push(country);
    $("g[data-name='"+country+"']").first().attr("data-owned", "true");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript at the time you mark the country as "owned", if you set the path's fill it should stop obeying the :hover selector, eg:

```
obj.style.fill = "#D2D2D2";
```

Example: http://iqgames.gjsite.com/ , after a country is colored green or red it no longer has a hover color.

Update: pretty sure it is because of the !important in your CSS.  If I add that to the path:hover selector in my page referenced above, it has the same behaviour as yours.

**To clarify, this is what I would try:**

1. Rethink the logic of your css rules to avoid using !important on anything that you will be using javascript to modify.
2. In your script when you assign a country as "owned", in addition to changing classes and data attributes, modify the fill/stroke directly using document.getElementById.

**Also:** Be aware jQuery does not fully support svg.

Comment: What code...on the page I linked to, or on yours?  What exactly did you try?

Comment: To what code?  You don't show your javascript at all, or any link to a web page.  "obj" is a reference to whatever <path> you are changing to be "owned", example: `code`obj=document.getElementById("sumatra")`code`

Comment: I added the javascript

Comment: and the link to the website

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you have !important in your css for the path hover fill?  If I add it to the page I referred you to, it behaves the same as yours, ignoring the style.fill set by the javascript.  Mine is simply: `code`path:hover {fill:yellow; stroke:black;}`code`

Comment: See here: http://iqgames.gjsite.com/WhereIsX.php ... the only difference is I added !important to the path:hover.  Now the hover is always yellow.

Comment: how did you the path stay selected?

Comment: As I first said, by assigning a fill and stroke directly using obj.style.fill="".  I originally tried simply changing the class of the path but that didn't work.  Also, you should be aware JQuery does not support many features of svg.